# Getting the source code of a function?

Tags: actionscript

Is there anyway I can get the code inside a function in Actionscript (Preferably AS1)?

For example, let's say I have this function:

```
function foo(){
    trace("bar");
}
```

Is there anyway I can get the text 'trace("bar");' from the function WITHOUT modifying the actual function?

Like this (psuedo code):

```
trace(foo.source);
```

Would trace the text 'trace("bar");'

Comment: Can the actionscript code be saved into a text file? If so then why not just load the text file and use `String` functions to `find` "function foo" and then extract everything between the following `"{"` and stop before the next found `"}"`. So basically croppping off text until you know whats written between the function brackets (and therefore getting the code for that function). You want to use `subString` or `subStr` if doing this

Comment: No, it can't. Like I said, I can't modify the actual function at all.

Comment: So how do you know this `function foo` even exists at all? Can you see it in the FLA? Why cant that be a good time to copy to external text file for anytime checking of function codes. If your function is really in some SWF then it cannot be done since SWFs are compiled (no longer just your text/graphics etc its now bytes of machine code). FlashPlayer is aware of function names so one SWF can load another SWF and even run the functions in that external SWF (if known).

Comment: I'm writing an extension for a Flash game with zero documentation. I know foo exists because when I trace(foo), it says "[Type function]". I can't find the foo function ANYWHERE, and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Is it possible that game swf is itself loading yet another swf (that might make it seem like game swf now has "non-existant" function when in fact they reside in the child swf it just loaded? Check  by running game swf in abrowser (like Chrome or FFox) where you can check file/server access. If there are multiple SWFs being accessed then one of those likely has **Function foo**

Comment: *RE:* "I can't find the foo function ANYWHERE..." have you tried decompiling game swf with [AS3 Sorcerer](http://www.as3sorcerer.com/download.html)? Thats good for showing code even when its obfuscated for unreadability. Let me know how it goes